# How to check if a statements is true, execute, and then reset this statement?

Tags: python

I have a live stream counter on my page.

1. When the ticker is over 10 I want it to flag "Congrats!" and then turn off
2. When the ticker is below 5 I want it to flag "Boo!" and then turn off
3. Must work when ticker hovers over 10 or below 5  multiple times. i.e. It will up and down throughout the game

Trying to get the basic code down, but I'm going through a series of if/else statements and past attempts haven't been working. For example the below only works once. Then when the ticker reaches 10 again, it won't prompt "Congrats"

```
while True:

    timerx += 1
    if (timerx >= 5):
        if flag == True:
            flag = False
            print("Congrats!")
        else:
            flag = True
    else:
        flag = True
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Most probably I would use a flagAbove and a flagBelow flag to keep track of what's happenening. Initiall both would be false, when you go above, you set set flag above and clear flag below, and the other way around for the below case. Would that work for you?

Comment: what do you mean by "turn off"?

Comment: @Tibebes.M It should print "Congrats!" only once. Even though it's above "5" for say one minute. Not "Congrats!" "Congrats!" "Congrats!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to memorize previous ticker value. Based on that you could decide do you need to `Boo!` or `Congrats!`. I implemented this logic via `class`:

```
class Ticker(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.previous = None

    def tick(self, tick):

        if tick < 5 and (self.previous is None or self.previous >= 5):
            print('Boo!')
        elif tick > 10 and (self.previous is None or self.previous <= 10):
            print('Congrats!')

        self.previous = tick

ticker = Ticker()
while True:
    for i in range(15):
        print(i)
        ticker.tick(i)
```

Sample output:

```
0
Boo!
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
Congrats!
12
13
14
0
Boo!
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
Congrats!
12
13
14
```